# How can I get my text top-aligned in a Word table cell?

Tags: microsoft-word, text-formatting

I'm creating a resume in Word using a template that I downloaded from elsewhere. The template is a table with two columns, the top row of which is shown here:

[image: top row of resume]

I want the text to align with the top of the cell; that is, I don't want any blank space between the top of the cell and the text, and I want the row height to be just enough to accommodate the text. Here's what I've tried:

- Both cells are aligned top left.
- The top cell margin is 0 inches.
- The before paragraph spacing is 0 pt.
- If I decrease the cell height, the cells shrink without pushing the text upward.

None of these have worked. Any ideas?

Comment: I assume that the paragraph Line Spacing (in Paragraph Properties) is set to “Single”.  For the top paragraph in each cell, try setting it to “Exactly”, with a size slightly smaller than the largest font in the top line.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this and was able to get get the text to move up a little, but if I shrink the line spacing too much the text gets cut off by an invisible line below the top of the cell. I'm still unable to move the text to the top of the cell.

Answer (score 7):

1. Set your focus inside the cell that you want to vertically align.
2. Right-click and choose Table Properties.
3. Under the Cell tab, choose Top for Vertical Alignment.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same issue. Go to the paragraph line spacing dropdown box and select 'Remove Space Before Paragraph'. Did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen in a cell. What I did was reformat the cell. The icon is in the Home tab under font. I clicked on the cell, reformatted it and the text popped up to the top of the cell. Don't know what was in the cell to keep text from moving to top. But reformatting did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

This just happened to me and I came here seeking an answer.. but as you can see I am creating my own response. Found out the way to adjust the word alignment would be in the ‘Layout’ tab (at the top of the Word Document). Next, a section titled ‘Alignment’ will have the positions you can format the text.